# Getting first 3 chars from "Job No." to use as filter - Jet Reports

Tags: excel, jet, dynamics-nav

I am struggling to get the Quantities from the Job Ledger Entries Table which I need to filter on the first 3 letters of the Job No. pulled from the Item Budget Entries..

I am new to Jet Reports and using Express.. I have tried the function:

[image: Attempt to get first 3 chars]

Should I add it as a line of code = to a variable then use the variable?

My table query looks like this so far:

```
=NL("Table";"Item Budget Entry";$E$12:$I$12;"Headers=";$E$11:$I$11;"TableName=";"Item Budget Entry";"Filters=";$C$5:$D$6;"InclusiveLink=Item Budget Entry";$E$10;"IncludeDuplicates=";"True")
```

With Filters:

[image: Filters for the table]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be hard to achive with the express version. In the Essentials version you are able to add Excel formulas to your table.

What I would do is create two tables, one with item budget entry and one with job ledger entry. And then use excel to calculate the sums.

Or use the Essentials version, which will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah I get you, well company isn't prepared to pay for the essentials version -> its rather pricey and we don't use it often enough to warrant this.